# Python- WebScraping a page

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code is supposed to go into a website, navigate through 2 pages, and print out all the titles and URL/href within each row.

Currently - My code goes into these 2 pages fine, however **it only prints out the first title** of each page and not each title of each row.

The page does have some JavaScript, and I think maybe this is why it does not show any links/urls/hrefs within each of these rows? Ideally id like to print the URLS of each row.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

for x in range (1,3):
    driver.get(f'https://www.abstractsonline.com/pp8/#!/9325/presentations/endometrial/{x}')
    time.sleep(3)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    eachrow=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='result clearfix']")
    for item in eachrow:
        title=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='bodyTitle']").text
        print(title)
```

Comment: I dont know if this helps but check Beautiful Soup Web Scraper on realpython -> [link](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/#building-the-job-search-tool)

Comment: BeautifulSoup doesnt seem to be able to parse this page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `driver` inside your for loop meaning you're searching the whole page - so you will always get the same element.

You want to search from each `item` instead.

```
for item in eachrow:
    title = item.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[@class='bodyTitle']").text
```

Also, there are no "URLs" in the rows as mentioned - when you click on a row the `data-id` attribute is used in the request.

```
<h1 class="name" data-id="1989" data-key="">
```

Which sends a request to https://www.abstractsonline.com/oe3/Program/9325/Presentation/694

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

I tried the line of code with item.find instead of driver.find and i get blank printed as an output. Do you get something printed on your end?

Comment: Thanks, interesting that the dot refines the seaches